# Mongodb find() with default parameter value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a fined edit of a previously posted question.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/BqS2cRvwQQR

query: zip = 94583, service="CPS" must return 1 entry: {
"outsort": "OAK",
"service": "CPS",
"zip": "94583"
}

Same zip for a diff service: zip = 94583, service="other" should return:{
"outsort": "VNW",
"service": "default",
"zip": "94583"
}

query: zip = 92021, service="ABC" woould return: {
"outsort": "SAN",
"service": "default",
"zip": "92021"
}

query: zip = 02135, service="CDF" should return no results (no match for zip)
This one is interesting: zip = 12345, service="BCD" should return NO RESULT, because there is no exact match for service, and NO DEFAULT ENTRY in the database!

Comment: i dont remember the previous question, can you make the data in JSON , like put them in code blocks, and add the question also, what is the question i dont remember, use something like [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print)

Answer (score 0):

A document passes is

- same zip and (same servive OR service="default")

Instead of "1" and "A" put your variables.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QHYRjf7Gskm)

Query (`$in` solution and find)  (its smaller)

```js
db.collection.find({
  "zip": "1",
  "service": {
    "$in": [
      "A",
      "default"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sFKwBc5fDe4)

Query (or solution and aggregate)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$zip",
              "1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "$or": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$service",
                  "A"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$service",
                  "default"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: dont worry i answered wrong question sometimes you read it and you think you understanded but you dont, i updated it i think now its ok, to avoid those you can give expected output data, they can help alot

Comment: Takis_ thanks again, I edited my question (too many details to put into a comment).

Comment: can you re-post your question, because i forgot it, also fix the data if you can to be JSON